# Detecting the monitor resultion with javascript on a secondary monitor

Tags: javascript

I want to detect the **monitor resolution** with **javascript**. This works fine with **screen.height** and **screen.width** on the primary monitor. On a **secondary monitor** (extended desktop) this doesn't work! When I **move the browser to the secondary monitor** and call my javascript function with the resolution detection, **screen.height** and **screen.width** have still the resolution values of the primary monitor.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I'm curious though, what are you after the resolution for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its my understanding that it will only return the values of the *Primary Monitor*. I believe a solution would have to come in at the browser level which would not be a Javascript based one.

Comment: Yeah, the browser determines which values to return for screen.height/width.  So, you'll have to petition the browser makers for detecting the browser window on the secondary monitor.  Having said that, it's probably best to not rely on those properties anyway.